# MongoDB Aggregation - How can I pad an field with zeros and letters on the left?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, projection

Can you help me with a situation... I Have this Json but I would like to format the field *trackingID* like **"TR000000012345BR"**. How can I pad a trackingId with letters and zeros on the left and letter on the rigth by aggregate?

```
[
  {
    "_id": "63f7aad063710fe0106dbc04",
    "name": "Kristen Welch",
    "address": "267 Dooley Street, Westphalia, New York, 1648",
    "trackingID": 963,
    "greeting": "Hello, Kristen Welch! You have 9 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "apple"
  },
  {
    "_id": "63f7aad0c156afad133a66b6",
    "name": "Shaw Roach",
    "address": "254 Newkirk Placez, Hiseville, American Samoa, 7644",
    "trackingID": 729,
    "greeting": "Hello, Shaw Roach! You have 7 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  }
]
```

I would like this result below:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "63f7aad063710fe0106dbc04",
    "name": "Kristen Welch",
    "address": "267 Dooley Street, Westphalia, New York, 1648",
    "trackingID": TR0000000963XP,
    "greeting": "Hello, Kristen Welch! You have 9 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "apple"
  },
  {
    "_id": "63f7aad0c156afad133a66b6",
    "name": "Shaw Roach",
    "address": "254 Newkirk Placez, Hiseville, American Samoa, 7644",
    "trackingID": TR0000000729XP,
    "greeting": "Hello, Shaw Roach! You have 7 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/8uUd7DVcW9R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "trackIngID": {
        $concat: [                                  //4. concatenate prefix and suffix
          "TR",
          {
            "$substrCP": [                          //3. remove leading 1
              {
                $toLong: {                          //2. convert to long
                  $add: [10000000000,"$trackingID"] //1. add 10000000000, to pad it with zeros
                }
              },
              1,
              10
            ]
          },
          "XP"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ky7Qsyl5iXJ)

Comment: Good trick, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. pad with 9 zeros at the start of the string with `$concat`
2. trim the extra leading zeros with `$substrCP`. Use `$strLenCP` and `$subtract` to calculate the offset.
3. `$concat` with the prefix 'TR' and suffix 'XP'

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "trackingID": {
        // pad with 9 zeros
        "$concat": [
          "000000000",
          {
            $toString: "$trackingID"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "trackingID": {
        // trim the extras leading zeros
        "$substrCP": [
          "$trackingID",
          {
            "$subtract": [
              {
                "$strLenCP": "$trackingID"
              },
              9
            ]
          },
          9
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "trackingID": {
        "$concat": [
          "TR",
          "$trackingID",
          "XP"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LB9_zEGLMEJ)